# js recursion function output question, function stack

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I have confusion on function recursion

```js
function foo(i) {
  console.log("checking: " + i);
  if (i < 0)
    return;
  console.log('begin: ' + i);
  foo(i - 1);
  console.log('end: ' + i);
}
foo(1);
```

why is the output:

```
checking: 1
begin: 1
checking: 0
begin: 0
checking: -1
end: 0
end: 1
```

it should not print the end: 0, end: 1, because we are returning in if condition. What is happening?

Answer (score 4):

`return` only terminates the *most immediately running* function.

```
foo(1)
  foo(0)
    foo(-1)
```

The

```
if (i < 0)
  return;
```

gets fulfilled on the third call, terminating the third function

```
foo(1)
  foo(0)
    foo(-1) <-- this function stops running
```

but leaving the other functions to continue as normal:

```
foo(1)
  foo(0) (execution resumes here, just after the foo(1) line)
```

It's possible to get out of *all* ancestor functions (up until a `.catch`, if any) by throwing an error, but such a strategy just for the sake of control flow isn't a great idea.

```js
function foo(i) {
  console.log("checking: " + i);
  if (i < 0)
    throw new Error();
  console.log('begin: ' + i);
  foo(i - 1);
  console.log('end: ' + i);
}
foo(1);
```

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance, if we use return keywork anywhere inside function it should comeout the function right, then why  interpreter comes to *console.log('end: ' +i);* line. Correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks

Comment: It only stops the most immediate call, not all calls of the function.

Comment: @RabindraKumarMahato the *current* running function is terminated. As the answer states, there are *three* different function calls. The third one finishes, the other two are still running.

Comment: @RabindraKumarMahato Because `return` finishes after giving the result ONLY in the current function. It really seems all function is finished after returning. Recursion is difficult I think so too!